# How to build and return object from Mono without using block()

Tags: mongodb, spring-webflux

How can we use values from Mono object to build and return a different object. I am trying to build a Printer object by retrieving Location object from database like this.

```
 private Printer buildPrinter(Location loc)
   {
   
     return locationRepo.getLocationById(loc.getLocationId())
           .flatMap(dbLoc -> {
                     Printer
                      .builder()
                      .locationName(dbLoc.getLocationName())
                      .build();

           });
   
   }
```

This doesn't seem to work they way I thought it would. What is the best way to consume and Mono and use it build and return object of different kind without getting out of the reactive context ?

Comment: it is completely impossible to return the item inside of a `Mono` or a `Flux` without calling either block or subscribe. Is this a web-flux application? and who started the call to this function? a webpage through a rest api?

Comment: Yes, this is web-flux application. The call to function is via api, which is supposed to lookup an information in mongo collection and save that information in another collection. I believe subscribe is non-blocking but I haven't found any good example of using it.

Comment: You should neither call subscribe or block if it is a webflux application. The answer to this question is that you should just simple return a `Mono<Printer>` to the calling client. The framework will handle all the subscribing for you. Your application is a producer. The calling client is the consumer, and it subscribes to your service.

Comment: I am dealing with two different database collections here, I need to retrieve data from one mongo collection and put it in another collection in an inter mediatory step. There should be some way to do that.

Comment: of course there is, but that wasn't the question. You asked how to return an object without calling block, and i have told you. It is completely impossible. You fetch whatever you have from a database, you flatMap the result and in that you put it in your second collection, and then you return the mono to the calling client. This is super basic beginner webflux. And not your original question.

Comment: @Toerktumlare. Yes, I am a beginner with webflux. Thanks for your responses anyway.